# Cannot Clear HTML Table in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my **Page Load** Method, I'm filling an HTML Table with Data.

By Default, the Table is empty.

```
<table runat="server" id="categoriesTable">
</table>
```

After I create each Row dynamically, I add 4 cells to it, and I give each cell an ID to be used later.

After creating all Cells, I re-traverse this Table so I can add inside each cell a list `<li></li>`, The Data inside these lists are fetched from a Database, which depends on the ID given to each Cell previously.

When I refresh the page, nothing goes wrong, but on `PostBack`'s (After clicking on some ASP Button, or changing the Selected Index of a DropDownList), the number of cells stays the same, but the list inside each cell is doubled.

Means, if I had this:

```
Cell1
-Da
-Do
-Di
-Du
Cell2
-Ya
-Yo
Cell3
-Ka
-Ki
```

I would have this after the PostBack:

```
Cell1
-Da
-Do
-Di
-Du
-Da
-Do
-Di
-Du
Cell2
-Ya
-Yo
-Ya
-Yo
Cell3
-Ka
-Ki
-Ka
-Ki
```

Here is the code, note that **cCategory** is a class that I created, and its methods return a `List<cCategory>`.

```
//Load Categories Into the Table
List<cCategory> mainCategoriesList = cCategory.SubCategories(null);
if(mainCategoriesList.Count!=0)
{
    //Categories Available
    HtmlTableRow Row = new HtmlTableRow();
    categoriesTable.Rows.Add(Row);
    HtmlTableCell Cell;
    int cellCounter = 0;
    while(cellCounter<mainCategoriesList.Count)
    {
        if (cellCounter % 4 == 0 && cellCounter!=0)
        {
            //Add a New Row
            Row = new HtmlTableRow();
            categoriesTable.Rows.Add(Row);
        }
        Cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        Cell.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"Category.aspx?id=" + mainCategoriesList.ElementAt(cellCounter).CategoryID() + "\">" + mainCategoriesList.ElementAt(cellCounter).Category()+ "</a>";
        Cell.ID = mainCategoriesList.ElementAt(cellCounter).CategoryID();
        Row.Cells.Add(Cell);
        cellCounter++;
    }
    //Now we must add the sub categories
    String subList = "";
    String newContents;
    int counter;
    List<cCategory> subCategoriesList;
    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //For each Row, go through each Cell
        for (int j = 0; j < categoriesTable.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            //For Each CELL, get the subCategories
            subCategoriesList = cCategory.SubCategories(categoriesTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].ID);
            counter = 0;
            while (counter < subCategoriesList.Count)
            {
                subList = subList + "<li><a href=\"Category.aspx?id=" + subCategoriesList.ElementAt(counter).CategoryID() + "\">" + subCategoriesList.ElementAt(counter).Category() + "</a></li>";
                counter++;
            }
            newContents = "<div class=\"subCategoriesList\"><ul>" + subList + "</ul></div>";
            subList = "";
            categoriesTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].InnerHtml = categoriesTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].InnerHtml + newContents;

        }
    }
}
```

Why is the Cell data getting doubled?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an IsPostBack() check in your Page_Load method where you are loading the table? I'm guessing not and that the rows are doubling because they are getting posted back via ViewState and you are adding them again via the above code.

Comment: If I add IsPostBack(), The Table will be loaded the first time, but after a PostBack, The Table will be empty, because it is empty by default, I think so.

Comment: If you have ViewState enabled, the table should remain populated after a postback. Have you tried it?

Comment: ViewState is enabled by default. And sorry, what I meant is have you tried adding the IsPostback?

Comment: if(Page.IsPostBack): Table will not be loaded at the beginning, it will be loaded after a PostBack.

if(!Page.IsPostBack): Table will be loaded at the beginning, it will be empty after a PostBack

Comment: It worked, the trick was to DISABLE the ViewState, thank you Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clean up [or remove the data of] the categoriesTable table first, then you do your logic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think this would be better as a comment as it doesn't attempt to answer the question. Check out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question for more info on writting answers